# The request signature we calculated does not match AMAZON AWS PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api

I have looked at most samples of code based on this issue on stack overflow but I still cant get the request to work. I keep getting this error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Here is my code:

```
$access_key = "ACCESS_KEY";
$associateTag = "AOSSOCIATE_TAG";
$secretkey = "SECRET_KEY";
$keywords = "harry%20potter";
$timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$operation = "AWSECommerceService";

function createSignature($operation,$timestamp,$secretkey){
    $the_string=$operation.$timestamp;  
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$the_string,$secretkey,true));
}

$signature = createSignature ($operation,$timestamp,$secretkey);

$APIcall = 
"http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?".
"AWSAccessKeyId=$access_key&".
"AssociateTag=$associateTag&".
"BrowseNode=1000&".
"ItemPage=1&".
"Keywords=$keywords&".
"Operation=ItemSearch&".
"ResponseGroup=Medium&".
"SearchIndex=Books&".
"Service=AWSECommerceService&".
"Timestamp=$timestamp&".
"Version=2011-08-01&".
"Signature=$signature";

$response = simplexml_load_file($APIcall);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why on earth are you bothering with this when there's a perfectly good, well supported PHP API available direct from Amazon? http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

Comment: Because I felt installing the SDK was a little over the top for what I wanted to achieve, I eventually just want to show perhaps 3 items from amazon in a sidebar based on a keyword and that's it, just felt doing it myself would be less bulky and quicker.

Comment: Installing the SDK takes a couple minutes. You've clearly spent at least that trying to do it yourself, troubleshooting, and posting here.

Comment: As of sep 2013, amazon has a working JS implementation of this which you can use as a reference: http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue long time and it worked for me with this code :

```
require_once 'Crypt/HMAC.php';
require_once 'HTTP/Request.php';

$keyId = "adasdasd";
$secretKey = "asdasdasdasdasd+";

function hex2b64($str) {
    $raw = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i+=2) {
    $raw .= chr(hexdec(substr($str, $i, 2)));
    }
    return base64_encode($raw);
}

function constructSig($str) {
    global $secretKey;
    $str = utf8_encode($str);   
    $secretKey = utf8_encode($secretKey);   
    $hasher =& new Crypt_HMAC($secretKey, "sha1");
    $signature = hex2b64($hasher->hash($str));      
    return ($signature);
} 


 $expire = time()+1000;
 $resource = "/demo/files/clouds.jpg";
 $date = gmdate("D, d M Y G:i:s T");
 $mime = "image/jpeg";

 $stringToSign = "PUT\n";
 $stringToSign .= "\n";
 $stringToSign .= "$mime\n"; 
 $stringToSign .= "$date\n";
 $stringToSign .= $resource;
 $req =& new HTTP_Request("http://nameofmine.s3.amazonaws.com/files/clouds.jpg");
 $req->setMethod("PUT"); 
 $req->addHeader("Date",$date);
 $req->addHeader("Authorization", "AWS " . $keyId . ":" . constructSig($stringToSign));
 $req->addHeader("Content-Type",$mime);  
 $req->setBody(file_get_contents($file_path));
 $req->sendRequest();
 $responseCode = $req->getResponseCode();
 $responseString = $req->getResponseBody();
 echo $responseCode;
```

As you see you have to use Crypto, HTTP pear plugins

Answer (score 0):

The function seems ok (it is the same as the one used in amazon AWS SDK) so make sure that there is no whitespace in front or after the copied key.

Answer (score 0):

When I typed in my credentials by hand, I got the same error a couple of times.

Then I tried Console for Windows so I could copy/paste my credentials. This removed the error message. Either I sucked at typing, or sucked at reading.

Long story short: Don't type by hand, copy and past credentials to avoid typos.

EDIT:
My problem was when trying to add my credentials via  EB CLIx3.